# How to prepare dataset for multivariate time series analysis using LSTM or RNNs?

Tags: time-series, multivariate-analysis, lstm

I am looking to use LSTM/RNN to perform time series prediction using some clinical data, however the structuring of the data might be an issue. I am fairly new to LSTM/RNN, would like to know how can I model the LSTM for my use case.

I have a dataset looking like this,

| ID | date | feature1 | feature2 | feature3 |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| person1 | date1 | value11 | value12 | value13 |
| person1 | date2 | value21 | value22 | value23 |
| person2 | date1 | value31 | value32 | value33 |
| person2 | date2 | ... | ... | ... |
| person3 | ... | ... | ... | ... |

I would like to perform a time series analysis to perform prediction based on each person's characteristics/features but based on my previous research and understanding most of the LSTM models are modelled based on lets say a singular person with multiple timestamps and data respectively. Given a data format/structure like mine, how can I go about training a LSTM model to perform predictions based on such features. The dates/years are the not the same for each person too.

Comment: Why do you want to use RNNs for this data? Do you have only two time points per person?

Comment: I do have multiple data points per person. I believe for time series prediction, it would be great incorporate LSTM/RNN for the predictions. I mean I am still quite new to LSTM/RNN methods and their specifics. Just wanted to know how can the data be structured for such a time series prediction case.